# Electron will not start at all

Tags: electron

I was working on a project and then I'm not quite sure if it did this when I was working on it or when I was away for awhile, but something has happened where electron is not starting, even if it's a brand new project.

I followed their quick-start guide to an absolute T (and have before plenty of times with no fail), but now it only gives me a error number of `2147483651` and Google hardly has anything about this error. I even cloned the `electron-quick-start` repo and still got the same error after running `npm install` successfully.

I've restarted my machine to see if there was any updates or hanging processes and still nothing.

EDIT: What's really confusing is it does start up a previous project. But I'm not sure why it's not even working with the cloned `quick-start` app.

Comment: Could you start from the command line and add the full error message to the question? Just the number is really not helpful and I never saw it failing like that. You could also add some `console.log` statement to the top of your `app.js` (or whatever is your start script) to see if starts executing the script or even stops before.
Is your nodeJS up to date?

Comment: It seems to be Electron 9.0.0 (presumably) with Windows 10 Insider Preview (19631.1). Electron 8.2.0 works fine though.

Comment: I suggest that you create a ticket on their issue tracker on github, if not done already. Maybe it's a known issue already and they'll respond there.

Comment: Thanks @ErraticFox! Downgrading to Electron 8.2.0 on Windows 10 Insider Preview worked.